# Flutter: ListView - Green overlay instead of arrows in widget inspector

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-layout

I'm creating a ListView with a builder function. I use the widget inspector to assess the any issues with the layout of the widgets.

Usually, the listView shows downwards green arrows as shown here:
[ListView layout][1]

However, in my current app, whenever I create a listView, it shows this green overlay on the listView. This creates artefacts with Image widget nested in stack; the images flicker when scrolling. [artefact layout][2]

This layout does look like it will take the space of 'drawer' in scaffold however, this page does not have a drawer, although all the other pages do.

Please find the code below for your reference.

````
  const BlogListPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BlogListPage> createState() => _BlogListPageState();
}

class _BlogListPageState extends State<BlogListPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: ASAppBar(
          title: const Text('Blogs'),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 10,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Container(
              margin:
                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0, horizontal: 24.0),
              color: Colors.amber,
              child: const SizedBox(
                height: 100,
                width: double.infinity,
              ),
            );
          },
        ));
  }
} ```

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7Pnc.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0g5HF.png
````

Comment: your code is working correctly what was the main problem?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0g5HF.png In this screenshot, you can see a green overlay on the ListView, I don't know what it is. Ideally it should show downward facing like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7Pnc.png

Comment: It's interfering with Image widget and making it flicker while scrolling the page.

Comment: Are you nesting Scaffolds ? You can easily check that by looking at the Flutter Outline tab on Android Studio.

Comment: I have kept that project on hold for now, but I'll check it out in some time and update.